# Short term power supply

Tags: power-supply, coil, backup, brownout

As a cheaper or longer lasting alternative to a battery, what else could maintain electricity for a second or two or more for a computer, PS4, TV or other similar devices when the lights are flickering, like during a storm as part of its design?

Comment: Uninterruptable power supply.  It's battery-based but since all these devices are AC powered, there's no way to e.g. put a capacitor in their DC rail(s) without an amount of effort and/or probability of destroying the device that makes it a superior alternative to a UPS.

Comment: @vir So the battery based back is the only way? What if one as you described was designed to do so perfectly

Comment: There's also "line voltage regulators" but they cost the same if not more than a small UPS.

Comment: @vir maybe one can absorb surges, correct for brown outs, and supply power for a second or 2?

Comment: That would be UPS.  Line voltage regulators can correct for some amount of "sag" on the line but not a complete loss of power.  Both usually incorporate surge protection.

Comment: The electricity in my area is reliable without brownouts or flickering. Also, there are very few storms. We cheer and have a party every five or ten  years when the electricity gets cut off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

- All of these are electronic devices; their power supply units already convert AC to DC, and then have a big set of capacitors that last 0.1 seconds or so (certainly they need to last at least longer than one AC cycle, 0.02 seconds). That's why sometimes the lights flicker but your computer *doesn't* reboot.

  *If you happen to be familiar with high-voltage power supplies* and safety precautions, you could add a whole bunch more capacitance in parallel, and extend this up to maybe 10 seconds or so, with 100 times the capacitance. (I wonder if supercaps can be useful here, however, you would need to chain more than 100 of them in series because they have very low voltage ratings.)
- If the device has an external power brick, then you can tap into the low-voltage side of the power brick, perhaps with a supercapacitor charger/discharger circuit board you got on AliExpress. I wouldn't suggest connecting the power brick directly to a supercapacitor because it is very likely to overload it.
- A flywheel UPS is a type of UPS that cannot store as much energy as one with a battery, but more than a capacitor bank. Energy is stored in a wheel spinning at high speed, connected to a motor, which keeps it spinning, and a generator, which takes power out so you can use it. (I assume that some of them use the same motor for both purposes, but if doing DIY, I wouldn't overcomplicate it) The wheel is heavy and spins fast, so it has lots of inertia to keep the generator turning if the power goes out. Professional ones last for 10-60 seconds or so. They are used for their higher reliability and lower maintenance compared to batteries.

Comment: If you hack the power supply and add 10x the capacitance, you are likely to blow the fuse or breaker when you plug in the mains. The components aren't rated to handle that kind of inrush current. Also, a standard ATX supply is only required to stay on for 17 ms under full load, so there may not be much money wasted on extra capacitors to last ten times that with ten times more space for input capacitors. At 50 Hz, one half cycle is 10ms, so full cycle of 20ms is just two half cycles.

Comment: @Justme I was thinking active power factor correction might handle it, but yes, you would certainly want to understand the circuit in some detail and not just slap them in there. Though maybe adding some moderate R is enough of a hack, idk, didn't calculate it.